# I have 4 degrees, what is the best way to find a job that takes advantage of all 4?

Tags: job-search

I have 4 degrees:

1. [B.S. Computer Engineering](https://ece.umd.edu/undergraduate/degrees/bs-computer-engineering)
2. [B.S. Mathematics](https://www-math.umd.edu/)
3. [M.S. Software Engineering](https://www.umgc.edu/online-degrees/masters/it-software-engineering)
4. [M.S. Electrical Engineering](https://www.csee.umbc.edu/graduate/electrical-engineering-m-s-ph-d/)

If you click on the links above you can find out more about the schools I went to and their programs.

My question: What is the best way to find open positions/jobs at companies that use all of my degrees?

If you go to a job search website (like indeed.com or google.com/jobs) you can type in search terms like "software engineer" or "Computer Engineer" or "Information Technology", and you'll see a bunch of search results for those specific fields.  But what if I'm looking for a position that requires knowledge from multiple fields?

Is there a website that keeps track of open positions that require knowledge from several fields ?

Comment: do you have Linkedin?

Comment: Have you considered a position in [Mechatronics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechatronics)?

Comment: @DarkCygnus - yes I do.  Are you suggesting I just let recruiters find me?

Comment: @IDDQD - Thanks -  I was not aware of Mechatronics.

Comment: @user1068636 with such a profile (4 degrees) I am sure recruiters would be interested, or at least come up in their searches... unfortunately job-searching is quite manual: you can post your profile, tidy it up, include tags and degrees, and wait for them to come, or you can actively search for available jobs of your liking, tailor a CV for it and send it... the best approach is to do both things.

Comment: @IDDQD, mechatronics has the advantage of being able to go get an ME degree first!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have 4 degrees, what is the best way to find a job

I would start with this

> that takes advantage of all 4?

and make this a "nice to have".

A lot of this depends on how you actually did acquire these degrees and how long it took you to do so. If you did all of these in parallel, you are an academic rock star and should have no problem getting into almost any company of your choice. If you did these all sequentially, than it will be very difficult to find a job at all since you are competing with people that have at least one degree and perhaps 10+ years more of actual job experience.

There are two basic routes: industry and academia. For many industry jobs degrees are not super relevant other than a check mark. In most places you need a degree to get some good understanding for the underlying theoretical foundations, but you'll learn how to to the actual work on the job. In my field (engineering, acoustics, physics): once you are 5 years into the workplace, no one cares what the subject of your degree and they care even less if it is Ph.D. M.Sc. or B.Sc.

Acadmedia is typically looking for depth not breadth. Some open minded faculties might actually embrace a broader perspective and additional skill set, but I have also seen faculties where this was deeply frowned upon because it's not "pure enough" and not a full commitment to the specific cause.

I don't know where exactly on the spectrum between rock-star to long-term-student you are, but I would recommend trying to find a job that you like and that gives you some hand on experience, even if you only use one of your degrees. Once you have a foot in the door, you can quickly see how the other skills may come in useful (or not).

Answer (score 2):

> What is the best way to find open positions/jobs at companies that use
> all of my degrees?
>
> If you go to a job search website (like indeed.com or google.com/jobs)
> you can type in search terms like "software engineer" or "Computer
> Engineer" or "Information Technology", and you'll see a bunch of
> search results for those specific fields. But what if I'm looking for
> a position that requires knowledge from multiple fields?

- Go to the job site of your choice.
- Search for the **roles** that you want.
- Read the job requirements for that role at each open job that is returned.
- Choose one that requires knowledge from multiple fields.

A multi-keyword search like this may work on some job sites:
https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=%22computer%20science%22%20and%20%22mathematics%22%20and%20%22software%20engineering%22%20and%20%22electrical%20engineering%22

In either case, you'll have to weed through the results and likely add more filters like locale and experience level.